# PHP File Upload returning extensions false

Tags: php, file-upload, mysqli

I have a form which is meant to upload articles to my database within this form I have a file upload field the objectives of my file upload is as follows:

1. Limit file extensions to image format
2. Rename file to something random
3. Create a new directory based on the ID of the entry into the database
4. Keep the extension of the file that is uploaded

Every time I hit the submit button the form seems to think I have tried to upload a file that isn't in the list of allowed extensions, it prints this error (the fields however are uploaded to the database):

```
wrong files format , allowed only "Array"
```

I'm not quite sure why this is the case as I know I'm inputting the correct file format.

```
    public function insert ($field) {

            if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO articles (title, story, storyb, storyc, author, date_created, section, youtubeid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

                        /* Set our params */

                         $title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['title']) : '';
                         $story = isset($_POST['story']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['story']) : '';
                         $storyb = isset($_POST['storyb']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['storyb']) : '';
                         $storyc = isset($_POST['storyc']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['storyc']) : '';
                         $author = isset($_POST['author']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['author']) : '';
                         $date_created = isset($_POST['date_created']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['date_created']) : '';
                         $section = isset($_POST['section']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['section']) : '';
                         $youtubeid = isset($_POST['youtubeid']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['youtubeid']) : '';

                        /* Bind our params */
                        $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $title, $story, $storyb, $storyc, $author, $date_created, $section, $youtubeid);

                        /* Execute the prepared Statement */
                        $stmt->execute();

                        /* Echo results */
                        echo "Inserted {$title} into database\n";

                        /* Close the statement */
                        $stmt->close();
                        }
                        else {
                        /* Error */
                        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
                        }

            // Handling file upload

            $extensions = array(".jpg",".jpeg",".gif",".png", ".JPG", ".JPEG", ".PNG", ".GIF");
            $extension = strrchr($_FILES['uploadImage']['name'], '.');

            $path =  "../files/uploads/articles_gallery/" . $this->mysqli->insert_id;
            $filename = uniqid(rand(), true);            


                if (!in_array($extension, $extensions))
                    {
                        echo'<center>wrong files format , allowed only <strong>"'.$extensions.'"</strong></center>';
                    }  else {

                            if (!is_dir($path))
                          {
                            die('Error: ' . $mysqli->error());
                          }

                                    echo "<h3>1 record added</h3>";
                                    mkdir($path, 0777);
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadImage']['tmp_name'], $path, $filename);
                    } // File Upload End

        }
```

Insert.php

```
<div id="form">
<form action="insert.php" method="post" name="insert" id="articleform">
            <input type="input" name="title" id="title" class="detail" id="title"/>
            <textarea name="story" id="story" class="detail" placeholder="Insert article here"></textarea>
            <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="uploadImage" onchange="PreviewImage();" class="" />
    <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 250px; height: 200px;" />
            <textarea name="storyb" id="storyb" class="detail" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Insert article here"></textarea>        
            <textarea name="storyc" id="storyc" class="detail" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Insert article here"></textarea>
            <input type="input" name="author" id="author" class="detail"/>
            <? $today = date("l j M Y");  // Monday 13 April 2013 ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="date_created" id="date_created" class="detail" value="<? echo $today;?>" />            
            <input type="hidden" name="section" id="section" class="detail" value="game"/>           
            <input type="input" name="youtubeid" class="detail" id="youtubeid" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Article    " />
        </form>
```

Comment: When debugging thinks like this I always try and output the comparing parameter as well as the list. (print both extension and extensions).
Also, your error message need to implode the array to be able to print it in the as a text. eg:
echo'<center>wrong files format , "'.$extension.'" allowed only <strong>"'.implode(", ",$extensions).'"</strong></center>';

Comment: -1 for mixing HTML, file upload, PHP and mysql into one question

Comment: Also, you way want to do your filename validations before you store the meta-info to the database. Or at least use a database transaction that roll back if the file is not accepted. If you don't do all your validation before storing the database record you will end up with missing files, that have records in the database

Answer (score 0):

update your form from:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" name="insert" id="articleform">
```

To :

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" name="insert" id="articleform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

[strchr()](http://php.net/strchr) will give you true/false if the character (in your case, ".") exists in the string. So to get the file extension, you could use something like:

```
$extension = end(explode('.', $filename));
```

.. But maybe a function like [pathinfo()](http://php.net/pathinfo) could be usefull in this case too.

Furthermore, in your error message you use `$extensions`. This is a var with type "array", and thus the string representation is "Array". I think you meant `$extension` (without the S) there. Or, maybe, you want to list all correct extensions this way: `implode(',', $extensions)`.

Note that checking on extensions is not a safe way to check what kind of content is present. I can easily upload a .exe, by just renaming it to .jpg.

Oh, and chmod-ing a directory/file to mode 777 is highly discouraged due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display the available extension you can't just concat your array with your message. you have to iterate all values.

Answer (score 0):

The code to get extension is wrong.

```
$extension = strrchr($_FILES['uploadImage']['name'], '.');
```

change it to

```
$extension = strtolower(substr($_FILES['uploadImage']['name'],-3,3));
```

if extension is 3 characters long or explode()
 and get the last parametr. This is not good way anyway, I prefer to check MIME type

```
$extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['uploadImage']['name'])));
```

change your extension array to

```
$extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png");
```

also add to your form

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

your error message is wrong because you want to echo array instead of string use implode() to join array

```
implode(";",$extensions)
```

Comment: thanks I tried this solution but I have got the following error `Fatal error: Call to a member function error() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Zaptube/admin/classes/class.Article.inc on line 79`